# PHP Form Upload - Extension invalid when file left blank

Tags: php, html, forms, post, file-upload

I have a php form which allows multiple uploads of the accepted extentions:

```
$allowedExtensions = array("pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","png","rtf","txt");
```

If extention isn't valid it enters this:

```
if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)) {
            die("File $file_name has the extensions $ext which is not allowed");
    }
```

At the moment I'm getting the error "File has the extensions which is not allowed" when a field is left blank. I have tried adding into the array an empty" ", is that what a blank file's extention would be?

What is the best way around this? Would it be to load in preset image when not filled in or does someone have a solution?

Here is the source code, maybe can help someone else:

```
<?php

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {

    $allowedExtensions = array("pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","png","rtf","txt");

    $files = array();
    foreach($_FILES as $name=>$file) {
        $file_name = $file['name']; 
        $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $file['type'];
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
        $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
        if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)) {
            die("File $file_name has the extensions $ext which is not allowed");

        }
        array_push($files,$file);
    }


    // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
    $to = "<info@xxx.co.uk>";
    $from = "<info@xxx.co.uk>"; 
    $subject ="test attachment"; 
    $message = "this is a test message";
    $headers = "From: $from";

    $band = $_POST['band'];

    // boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    // multipart boundary 
    $message = $band;
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachments
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
        $file = fopen($files[$x]['tmp_name'],"rb");
        $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]['tmp_name']));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $name = $files[$x]['name'];
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }
    // send

    $ok = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    if ($ok) { 
    echo "<p>photos sent!</p>"; 
    } else { 
        echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>"; 
    } 
}   

?>
```

Comment: you need to check if the file is set before running the upload function

Comment: Try using `&& empty($_FILES[$name])`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks alot! That has made it send the photos that have been inserted and gives the user error messages for the fields left blank, when before even if you entered 4 images if the fifth was blank none would send so that's great. The error messages are:`Notice: Undefined index: extension in x.php on line 16

Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in x.php on line 48

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in x.php on line 49

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in x.php on line 50
photos sent!`

Comment: It also allows any extention to be sent now if it is `if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions) && empty($_FILES[$name])) {
   die("File $file_name has the extensions $ext which is not allowed");
   
  }`